# What is valgrind trying to say?

Tags: c++, valgrind

Valgrind error

```
==157917== Invalid write of size 8
==157917==    at 0x4010C8: sdds::Ship::operator+=(sdds::Engine) (Ship.cpp:77)
==157917==    by 0x401A47: main (main_prof.cpp:101)
==157917==  Address 0x5a24408 is 120 bytes inside a block of size 160 free'd
==157917==    at 0x4C2BB8F: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:651)
==157917==    by 0x401097: sdds::Ship::operator+=(sdds::Engine) (Ship.cpp:76)
==157917==    by 0x401A47: main (main_prof.cpp:101)
==157917==  Block was alloc'd at
==157917==    at 0x4C2AC38: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
==157917==    by 0x400FC5: sdds::Ship::operator+=(sdds::Engine) (Ship.cpp:70)
==157917==    by 0x401A47: main (main_prof.cpp:101)
```

Due to the code being really big im going to try to do my best to provide all the necessary information.

```
Engine *m_engines;
        char *m_type;
        int m_engCnt;
```

Where I think the problem is coming from. The point of this function here is to create a temp array that is one larger than the original. Then i would copy the original values to the new array. Reassign the original array to point to the new array. Then copy the new engine into a resized array. What mistake did i do that cause the valgrind error?

```
 Ship& Ship::operator+=(Engine engine)
    {
        if (m_type != nullptr && strlen(m_type) > 0 && m_engines != nullptr)
            {
            Engine* resize_arr = new Engine[m_engCnt +1];
            for(int i =0;i<m_engCnt;i++)
            {
            resize_arr[i]=m_engines[i];
            }
            delete[] m_engines;
            m_engines = resize_arr;
            delete[] resize_arr;
            m_engines[m_engCnt++] = engine;
            }
        else
        {
            cout << "The object is not valid! Engine cannot be added!" << endl;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

when i delete [] m_engine before  reassigning it " m_engines = resize_arr;"
I get the following error :

```
==160760== Invalid write of size 8
==160760==    at 0x4010E3: sdds::Ship::operator+=(sdds::Engine) (Ship.cpp:78)
==160760==    by 0x401A63: main (main_prof.cpp:101)
==160760==  Address 0x5a24408 is 120 bytes inside a block of size 160 free'd
==160760==    at 0x4C2BB8F: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:651)
==160760==    by 0x4010B2: sdds::Ship::operator+=(sdds::Engine) (Ship.cpp:77)
==160760==    by 0x401A63: main (main_prof.cpp:101)
==160760==  Block was alloc'd at
==160760==    at 0x4C2AC38: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:433)
```

Comment: `m_engines = resize_arr; delete[] resize_arr;` This deletes the pointer just assigned, so `m_engines` is left pointing to invalid/freed space now. You probably want to delete the old `m_engines` pointer, first, then assign the new one.

Comment: It also leaks whatever `m_engines` was pointing to.

Comment: @dxiv, hey i actually tried doing that before it just caused another error. i posted the error above

Comment: Change line 11(from writed code) to this:                                      delete resize_arr[]

Comment: @PeterTran Post the actual code. The line numbers in the error do not match what you say you changed.

Comment: @GobeRadJem32 That's nonsense.

Comment: @dxiv i added the change in the code where i put delete[] m_engine

Comment: @PeterTran Remove the `delete[] resize_arr;` line. See my first comment why. You only `delete` pointers that you `new`'d, you only delete them once, and only when they are no longer used/needed.

Comment: @dxiv sorry i didnt quite get what you were saying, It was actually correct  but i dont get why? I thought that i would have to clear the temp array ?

Comment: @PeterTran What do you mean by "*temp*" array? The array that you `new`'d into `resize_arr` is the *same* array that `m_engines` points to after you assign `m_engines = resize_array;`. Pointer assignment just copies the pointer value, which is the starting address of the array.